# How can i associate a sentence to a dictionary when all the sentence's keywords are contained in the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dictionary

I have a sentences df like this:

```
df_sentences

                        Answers
0   Gracias por el tiempo dedicado a compartir un...
1   Nos es grato saber que han disfrutado durante...
2   Gracias por trasladarnos su amable opinión sob...
3   Nos complace saber que tanto nuestras instala...
4   Esperamos poder darle la bienvenida de nuevo e...
... ...
225239  Nos complace leer que le hayan gustado los se...
225240  Gracias de nuevo por ilustrar su experiencia,...
225241  Reciba un cordial saludo
225242  no podemos pedirle más al año nuevo, la valo...
225243  Confiamos en poder ofrecerles nuestros servici...
```

And i have another df, which contains a dict for each sentence, and inside this dict, there are the sentences' keywords. Each dict for each sentence is like this:

```
{'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.977459, 'label': 'positive'}},
 'language': 'es',
 'keywords': [{'text': 'hotel Occidental',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.977459, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.79789,
   'count': 1},
  {'text': 'Playa de Palma',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.977459, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.640675,
   'count': 1},
  {'text': 'Gracias',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.977459, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.490027,
   'count': 1},
  {'text': 'buena valoración',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.977459, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.485875,
   'count': 1},
  {'text': 'comentario',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.977459, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.287868,
   'count': 1},
  {'text': 'experiencia',
   'sentiment': {'score': 0.977459, 'label': 'positive'},
   'relevance': 0.279029,
   'count': 1}]}
```

I have extracted all the keywords for each dict, and stored them into lists like so:

df_dicts

```
                Dicts                                      Keywords
0   {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.977459,...   [hotel Occidental, Playa de Palma, Gracias, bu...
1   {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.868795,...   [grato saber, vacaciones, futuro]
2   {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.908815,...   [amable opinión, Gracias, trasladarnos, experi...
3   {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.862444,...   [parte del personal del hotel, instalaciones, ...
4   {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.977293,...   [futuro cercano, bienvenida]
... ... ...
213821  {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.966099,...   [servicios, hotel]
213822  {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.992032,...   [futuro próximo, Gracias, experiencia, verlos]
213823  {'sentiment': {'document': {'score': 0.750927,...   [cordial saludo]
```

I have a problem with these data:

There's a dict for each sentence, the problem is that i have more sentences than dicts, so i need to find out which sentences match with which dicts. The approach i was using was to write a program that loops over the sentences and dicts row wise, and for each sentence it checks each keyword list. If all the keywords in the list are in the sentence, then it's a match, and it should return `True`, if not, it returns NO or `False`.

I have tried with this loop, but it is extremely slow and complex:

```
#Match sentences based on their keywords

answer_sentences_list=[]
for i in range(len(df_sentences.Answers)):
    if((i%10000)==0):
        print(i)
    match=False
    for j in range(df_sentences.shape[0]):
        counter=0
        sentence_list=[]
        for keyword in df_dicts.Keywords.iloc[j]:
            if(keyword in df_sentences.Answers[i]):
                counter=counter+1        
        if(len(df_dicts.Keywords.iloc[j])==counter):
            sentence_list.append(df_sentences.Answers[i])
            match=True
    if(match):
        answer_sentences_list.append(sentence_list)
    else:
        answer_sentences_list.append("NO")
```

Is there any better/faster way to do this?? in an hour it has looped ony over 10000 sentences/dicts and i have like 200000 +. I would be really thankful if someone could improve this code to make it faster or suggest a different/better way to achieve this.

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT:**

Here's a link to a sample of each df for those who would like to play and test thing on these:

[df_dict](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qh-4SdR-yXi8GkCq1rinVA-gsMg6LMX5)

[df_sentences](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1snvUISXmw4sLSswC5eZU7wQWbj9zmuSc)

Answer (score 1):

Don't iterate through list in such way as:

```
for i in range(len(df_sentences.Answers)):
    answer = df_sentences.Answers[i]
    ...
```

Do it pythonic way:

```
for answers in df_sentences.Answers:
    ...
```

And don't compare words sets here by iterating through all words. You can use set objects for this:

```
if(set(keywords) == set(answers)):
    ...
```

And more of it. You can find lengths of answers and keywords beforehand and compare only sets with equal length. And so on (sort lists by len, for example, for early stopping of comparation; also you can make some hash code for these sets and compare only sets with equal len and hash code).
All of it should speed up this process.